# Обнуление или завершение метода async Task

Tags: c#

Как завершить выполнение метода MyMethod() при повторном нажатии Obzor_Click

```
  private async void Obzor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => await MyMethod();

    public async Task MyMethod()
    {

        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "Text documents (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        dialog.FilterIndex = 2;

        Nullable<bool> result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {

            // Open document


            string filename = dialog.FileName;


           var accounts = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Select(x => x.Split(':')).Select(x => new { User = x[0], Password = x[1] });



            foreach (var account in accounts)
            {
              var manager = new MailRuManager();
                await manager.Login(account.User, account.Password);
            ...
            }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98963/discussion-on-question-by--reyz-----async-task).

Comment: В цикле foreach добавить. Если кнопка не нажата. if (Obzor == null) {
                        return;
                    }